# Using complex statements in SQL queries multiple times in multiple ways

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

I am designing a `View` on a `Microsoft SQL Server 2008` that should be built upon quite a lot of business logic, meaning there is a lot of `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE` statements. The thing is, result from one `CASE` statement is often needed in other places in the query, such as functions, joins and another cases. This makes the code extremely bloated, harder to read and harder to maintain.

Below is an example of such a view (fields and functions merely illustrative):

```
SELECT

    -- Random complicated case
    CASE
        WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
        THEN D-A
        WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
        THEN D-A - 5
        WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
        THEN D-A - 10
        WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
        THEN D-A - 15
    END AS ComplicatedCase

    -- Use of that same complicated case in another case
    CASE
        WHEN CASE
                WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A
                WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 5
                WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 10
                WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 15
             END > 300
        THEN CASE
                WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A
                WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 5
                WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 10
                WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 15
             END 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AnotherCase

FROM SomeTable AS T
    -- Complicated case in join
    INNER JOIN AnotherTable AS AT
        ON  AT.ID = CASE
                        WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                        THEN D-A
                        WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                        THEN D-A - 5
                        WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                        THEN D-A - 10
                        WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                        THEN D-A - 15
                    END
```

The code is long, unreadable an I am more likely to forget to change on occurrence if a change in business logic is required.

The obvious solution that occurred to me is having the case in a sub select, either joined by an `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY` like this:

```
-- Solution by CROSS APPLY sub-select
SELECT
    T1.ComplicatedCase,
    CASE
        WHEN ComplicatedCase > 300
        THEN ComplicatedCase
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AnotherCase

FROM SomeTable AS T
    CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A
                WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)=D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 5
                WHEN A=B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 10
                WHEN A<>B AND CAST(C AS int)<>D AND DATEDIFF(DAY,E,F) > 5
                THEN D-A - 15
            END AS ComplicatedCase
        FROM SomeTable AS ST
        WHERE T.ID = ST.ID
        ) AS T1

    INNER JOIN AnotherTable AS AT ON AT.ID = T1.ID
```

...and that works fine, but I don't know if the query performance wouldn't suffer on a large scale (as I don't know much how the engine handle this stuff internally).

Do you have any best practices on how to handle complex statements like this? Does it even matter to the SQL engine if it is in a simple joined sub-select?

PS: My case statements usually consists of several functions, mostly of `datetime` handling and conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you have to `CROSS APPLY` your `SomeTable` twice.

This should work:

```
SELECT T1.ComplicatedCase
    , CASE
        WHEN ComplicatedCase > 300 THEN ComplicatedCase
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AnotherCase
FROM SomeTable AS T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, T.E, T.F)
    ) AS TT(DayDiff)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
            WHEN T.A = T.B  AND CAST(T.C AS INT) = T.D  AND TT.DayDiff > 5 THEN D - A
            WHEN T.A <> T.B AND CAST(T.C AS INT) = T.D  AND TT.DayDiff > 5 THEN D - A - 5
            WHEN T.A = T.B  AND CAST(T.C AS INT) <> T.D AND TT.DayDiff > 5 THEN D - A - 10
            WHEN T.A <> T.B AND CAST(T.C AS INT) <> T.D AND TT.DayDiff > 5 THEN D - A - 15
        END
    ) AS T1(ComplicatedCase)
INNER JOIN AnotherTable AS AT
    ON AT.ID = T1.ComplicatedCase;
```

`CROSS APPLY` allows you to create calculated values and use them in `JOINS`, `WHERE` statement and so on. It makes code much more readable and it shouldn't cost extra resource for you.

If something's unclear or doesn't meet your criteria - let me know.

Comment: Hi @Evaldas,I don't see much of a difference between your solution and mine, apart from correct table referencing. But I like the idea of using CROSS APPLY just for the DATEDIFF. Does this make a difference for the SQL engine or is it just for readability? Also, what does it mean to assing an alias to a subselect with brackets? Like this: AS TT(DayDiff)... I have not seen this before. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @MarekStejskal, difference I see, that you're making a reference between `SomeTable` twice when it's not needed (at least it looks like that for me), which is extra cost, see here: http://prntscr.com/71csl1. It shouldn't make any notable difference for SQL Server engine, it just maintains readability. And for your second question - it's just another way to assign aliases. I'm used to do that for `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY`.